# Separating Webmatrix Queries into C# classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

The code below obviously won't work. I am not familiar with how to return dynamically typed variables.

```
public class Db
{
   public static var GetUsers()
    {
        var db = Database.Open("Db");
        var sql = "SELECT FirstName FROM Users";
        return db.Query(sql)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dynamic keyword:

```
public static dynamic GetUsers()
{
    var db = Database.Open("Db");
    var sql = "SELECT FirstName FROM Users";
    return db.Query(sql)
}
```